# Reverse sort a 2d numpy array in python

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array like:

```
A = array([[-inf,  4,  5,  10, -inf, 1],
            [-inf,  2,  6, 8, -inf, 1],
            [-inf,  4,  -inf,  10, -inf, 100]
      ])

I need to sort in a decreasing order: 

A = array ([ 10,5,4,1,-inf,-inf], 
          [8,6,2,1,-inf,-inf],
           [100,10,4,-inf,-inf,-inf]])
```

Here `-inf` is `float('-inf')`
How Do I do this?

I tried this:
`sorted(A, key=lambda listA: len(listA), reverse=True)`

But I am not getting the sorted array. Can someone please tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 5):

How about

```
A.sort()
A[:,::-1]
```

?

References :

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.sort.html

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html

Comment: Since his array is 2D, it'll be rather ``[:,::-1]``.

Comment: I am getting :TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: `A.sort()` sorts array in place.