# How to sort half of the 2d array in descending order (numpy)

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy

I'm trying to create an array (10000, 50) size (I'm mentioning the size because efficiency is important), and then :

- Sort the first 5000 rows in ascending order
- Sort the next 5000 rows in descending order.

Here is my code :

```
samples = 10  # I'm going to increase it 10000
sampleLength = 4 # I'm going to increase it 50
halfSamples = int(samples/2)

xx = numpy.multiply(10, numpy.random.random((samples, sampleLength)))
xx[0:halfSamples,0:sampleLength]=numpy.sort(xx[0:halfSamples,0:sampleLength],axis=1)
xx[halfSamples:samples,0:sampleLength]=numpy.sort(xx[halfSamples:samples,0:sampleLength],axis=1)
```

This sorts both half of the array in ascending order, the only thing I can't find is what parameter to give in my last line to make it in a descending order.

I've tried based on this link : [Reverse sort a 2d numpy array in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27054368/reverse-sort-a-2d-numpy-array-in-python)

```
xx[halfSamples:samples,0:sampleLength]=numpy.sort(xx[halfSamples:samples,0:sampleLength:-1],axis=1)
```

But got an error :

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (5,0) into shape (5,4)
```

Thanks

Comment: Append `[:,::-1]` at the end of the last line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would probably be faster to sort the array in place using its [`.sort`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.sort.html) method, rather than [`np.sort`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html) which returns a copy. You can index the second dimension using a negative step size to sort the columns of the last 5000 rows in descending order:

```
x = np.random.randn(10000, 50)
x[:5000].sort(axis=1)
x[-5000:, ::-1].sort(axis=1)
```

Comment: What is the meaning of the -5000, why is it the same as 5000:10000 ?

Comment: Negative indexing is relative to the end of the array, so `x[-5000:]` indexes the 5000th row from the end of the array onwards. `x[-1]` would give you the last row, `x[-10:]` would give you the last 10 rows etc.